# Displaying SimpleMarkerSymbol in a button

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology

I'm making a button that the user can click and it will bring up the symbol selection window. I'm trying to make it such that after the user has made a selection, the symbol that they select is also displayed inside the button.

Is this possible?

Comment: This might be possible but it may be impractical. One example I can think of currently within ArcMap is the drawing toolbar. The line below the marker/fill/text color selectors do change depending on the color you currently have selected. This might be a starting place to look for example code.